# How to prevent duplicate title tags for multilingual content

Tags: seo, google, title-attribute

Google is reporting duplicate title tags for a website that is built for 2 languages.

The URL structure seems fine it is something like:

```
example.com/place-1
example.com/fr/place-1
```

The title tags are unique for each page yet some info is of course duplicated for the other language, for example:

```
Place-1 - Region - Gourmet lunch and dinner
Place-1 - Region - Dîner gastronomique
```

1. Why would this be considered a duplicate when they clearly are not the same.
2. Even if they were the same the `<title>` is important and unique for each language, how can I tell google this.

Comment: Are the pages direct automated translations? or hand written? because if so this could be way - if you haven't already I suggest you check out http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192#1

Comment: These are legitimate translations by a human.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate content translated into different languages is **NOT** considered duplicate content by Google.   Many large websites are translate all their content into several languages.  Far from being a problem, they enjoy good rankings in each of these languages.

Google even allows same language content to be duplicated when targeted to different countries.  You could have a co.uk and a com.au site which have the same content with some minor spelling difference and prices in different currencies.  Even two same language sites with nearly identical page titles would not be considered duplicate content.  They just need to be targeted correctly.  This can either be done automatically by the top level domain, or by setting the targeting via Google Webmaster Tools.

If you are having problems with duplicate content, your url structure could be part of the problem.  Your English content could be moved to a directory similar to your French content.  Something like `example.com/en/place-1`.  I personally use `example.com` and `fr.example.com` without problems for English and French respectively.

Google also gets confused if you mix languages within the same page.  Make sure your French pages don't have *any* English content on them.  This is one of the many suggestions in [Google's guide to working with multi-regional websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html)
.

Another hint you can give to Google is rel alternate links either in meta tags on your pages or in your sitemap files.  Google describes how to do this in this post about [multilingual and multinational site annotations](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site.html).

Comment: My question was specifically about `<title>` tags, Google webmaster has flagged duplicates for the 2 languages for only title meta, my example above is a real example that is flagged.

Comment: I suspect that it is confused somehow about the language of your pages.  I run a site translated into 40 languages and have never had a problem like that.  Make sure that Google is understands that you have sites in two languages and that the pages are the same but in an alternate language.

Comment: I think you may be right, the markup might be confusing Google such as the link to the +1 for Google in the french side had `{lang: "en-US"}` in the HTMl and a couple other minor words including "English", I will change these. I'll report back to see if this was the case, it might be a while.

Comment: The major problem with using fr.example.com is that the sub domain will need a fair amount of back linking too since back links are not shared globally on a domain. However it may be easier to rank if you have french links > going to the french domain and English going to the www. site since they will be more relevant but long as you know this before you proceed, you will lose rankings if you do so but long term it might be stronger to do so. This is why a lot of sites have decided to use /country/ rather than country.domain since its consider easier to work on the authority you already have..

Comment: These days sub-domains inherit authority the same way that folders do.  The biggest difference is your ability to host a subdomain in a different country closer to your users.

Comment: Sadly I'll have to disagree with you on that, sub domains do not inherit any juice or authority other than the backlinks you have going to the sub domain from the www. domain. Otherwise you'd have a million user.wordpress.com sites topping rankings, one major reason why so many sites went from secure.domain or shop.domain to /shop/ because a lot of juice is leaked and authority is not passed.

Comment: Google makes puts in algorithms to detect when subdomains are each owned by a different person.   The same way they do for folders in the case of a site like geocities where every user gets a folder.

Comment: Basically its debatable and unconfirmed but I covered this before for my own clients and correct me if I'm wrong more SEO'ers believe that none authority is passed over it is. Check out http://www.whitefireseo.com/site-architecture/subdomain-or-subfolder-post-panda/360/ its a good read. Stack Exchange works because of the sheer amount of content produced and natural links they have coming in, there is better suited reasons for making sub domains. I think its down to the individual on the size of the site.

Comment: I know what your saying but that rule would only apply to the bigger sites like GEOSITES, yet people have reported that rankings dramatiicly improve using sub folders over sub domains on things like shops. And we know that Link juice is not passed for a fact, hence 0 page rank, we can only assume thats the same as I've created sub domains and never shot up on rankings and if it was based on my own sites authority I'm sure I would. But again its a debatable topic and personally I'd only recommend sub domains as a last resort and if its ideal i.e thousands of pages.. pointless if its a small 1.

Comment: I would assume that your multiple languare site ranks well because your interlinking from the top level domain down to the sub domains which is passing the juice which in turn would make them rank, but not as strong as them in sub folders. But again, I'm not saying I'm right or you are either. It's unconfirmed and can only go on what I read, both cases is possible. If you find any pages that are on this topic, please let me know as I'm always keen to learn new things, Google changes their system daily and this may be the case nowadays its hard to stay on track until someone corrects you.

Comment: The big advantage of `fr.example.com` vs `example.com/fr` is that you can buy a server in France and point the DNS for the subdomain to it.  Then your website is much faster for French users.